# Is it possible to display bugs of different projects in same Sprint(Backlog or Kanban)

Tags: tfs, kanban, backlog

I have two different projects within same Project Collection.
Is it possible to display the bugs of both the projects in same backlog or kanban board.

Comment: You should merge your team projects and use Teams instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue myself and found a solution when switched to [Kanban Tool](http://kanbantool.com); simply by creating swimlanes on one Kanban board (one swimlane for each project) and then allowing bugs to be placed in the backlog and further development tasks in the next columns. So I have a complete view across many projects in one board. Happy to share my findings.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you cannot show work items from multiple Team Projects on a single Kanban board in TFS.

Kanban boards in TFS are currently associated with an Iteration Path. An iteration path only exists within the context of a Team Project. As such, Kanban boards by their current implementation live only within a Team Project.

As @Wouter stated, you could move the two projects into the same Team Project and use different iteration paths or area paths to differentiate your work items. This is actually a best practice. The name "Team Project" was actually a poor choice because they a Team Project isn't really mean to be the same as an actual development project. This has led to much confusion because it is not recommended to create a "Team Project" per actual project. It makes reporting and visualization a real problem.

Remembering that iteration paths are a hierarchical attribute, if you move both of the projects into the same Team Project, you can create an iteration path for each under the root and you can then get Kanban boards for each project. The root of the iteration path will also have a Kanban board and this board will be the rolled up board that shows all of the bugs from both projects on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have information from different Team Projects, you can create your own query. By default, the queries limit their results to the current project but you can easily remove this clause. You will then get results returned from all projects you have access to. [MSDN can help you get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576358.aspx) with creating queries.

However, it sounds you are looking into having data from multiple teams roll up into a single project. This is supported by using one Team Project with multiple Teams beneath it and using features from Agile Portfolio Management. See MSDN: [Agile Portfolio Management: Using TFS to support backlogs across multiple teams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306083.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

"You could create a query for each collections"

OR

"Create a query like this and select the “Query across projects” checkbox to find all workitems in the current collection"

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/122305/all-work-items-from-all-projects.html

[image: Tfs show all]